# Date format issue in Kendo Grid with inline editing

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-datepicker

I wrote such schema for my date  field:

```
  StartDate: { type: "date", format: "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}" }
```

and  a column definition:

```
  {
     field: "StartDate",
     title: "Start Date",
     template: '#= StartDate!=null ? kendo.toString(StartDate, "dd/MM/yyyy"): " " #',
     width: 100
  }
```

But I still see dates in format `MM/dd/yyyy` in `datepicker` during edition:

[image: wrong date format]

And if I try to write date manually in `dd/MM/yyyy` format I see:

[image: validation exception]

Comment: Try by setting up datepicker  date format. For datepicker default date format is " dd/MM/yyyy", you have to set format then it will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting culture is solved this issue

```
 kendo.culture("en-GB")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a `format field`, like this:

```
columns: [{
    field: "StartDate",
    format: "{0: dd/MM/yyyy}"
    // ...
}]
```

Comment: It works for selection with datepicker but if I type date manually still see validation message. Also after saving and reloading page dates with Day more than 12 is not displaying

Comment: I'm not sure if it right way but this line kendo.culture("en-GB") on the page with Grid resolved my issue